# Chrome console logs wrong typescript file and lines while serving production data

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome

Issue: [image]

When i console.log output to chrome, it always set's the output line as vg-overlay-play.ts (Videogular2 module) class.
This happens only in chrome, as the correct file is displayed when im using fx. firefox.

I'm using angular (6) and im serving production data on localhost.
The setup for serving production in `angular.json` is not any different from the development serve, except i replace the files from dev.ts to prod.ts environment.
Furthermore, the vg-overlay-play.ts file only gets created, when i'm serving production data.

This is the compiled sources in development:
[image: This is the compiled sources in development]

And this is the sources in production where the vg-overlay-play.ts file has been created:
[image: And this is the sources in production where the vg-overlay-play.ts file has been created]

Has this occured to anyone else, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe using sourcemap?